# What is the maximum number of red cards a club has received in a single game?

Tags: football, trivia

What is the maximum number of red cards a club has received in a single game? Please include any relevant match/ player details.

Comment: Some related questions: [What is the most red cards issued by the referee in one game of soccer/football?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3101) (Restricted to European top flight leagues.) [What is the maximum number of red cards that a referee can give in a football match?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1862) (Asking whether there is a theoretical upper limit.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick Google search gave me [this story published by Independent in 2011](https://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/news-and-comment/referee-brandishes-36-red-cards-in-one-match-2232288.html) where a referee expelled *all* players, substitutes and coaches included, of *both* teams. That meant each club received 18 red cards.

> A referee has set a record by showing 36 red cards in a single game, dismissing all the players, substitutes and coaches.
>
> The crazy scenes occurred in the fifth tier of Argentinean football between rival teams [Claypole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Club_Atl%C3%A9tico_Claypole) and [Victoriano Arenas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoriano_Arenas).
>
> With two players already dismissed in the first half, the second descended into chaos when players went lunging into tackles and there were repeated stand-offs between them. It boiled over when a mass brawl erupted that saw the managers and coaches enter the pitch with their fists flying. Some fans were also seen joining in.
>
> Referee Damian Rubino would later file his match report, in which he saw fit to serve every player with a red card, along with a further 14 people, a mixture of subs and coaches.

Answer (score 2):

There is another game with 36 red cards.

([Mass brawl leads to referee brandishing 36 red cards in one match](https://www.independent.co.uk/sport/football/news-and-comment/mass-brawl-leads-to-referee-brandishing-36-red-cards-in-one-match-8223041.html))

> A referee in South America has achieved the remarkable feat of sending
>   off more people than there are players on a pitch when he brandished
>   36 red cards in a junior league match.
>
> The match in Paraguay between Teniente Farina and Libertad took a turn
>   for the worse when referee Nestor Guillen dismissed two players in the
>   dying minutes of the match. The pair ignored the referee and continued
>   their feud on the pitch.
>
> Within moments, players from both sides became involved in a mass
>   brawl in which flying kicks and punches were thrown.
>
> The referee and his fellow officials, rather than trying to break up
>   the melee, instead fled the scene.